# Openweathermap не работает без VPN

Tags: c#, api, vpn, openweathermap

Нужно создать приложение погды на C#.
В теории все просто, но на практике все туторы на С# котороые я находил используют openweathermap, а у меня на этом сайте даже залогиниться без включения VPN в браузере не получается. Не удивительно что и приложение не может достучаться до сервиса и каждый раз возвращает респонс 404.

вот на всякий случай код, хотя я сомневаюсь, что тут что то может быть не так

```
CityName = "Omsk";
        API_KEY = "368e827be4b38db51ff960ca88b5c396";

        weburl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CityName + "&mode=xml&APPID=" + API_KEY;
        //weburl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=368e827be4b38db51ff960ca88b5c396";

        doc = new XmlDocument ();

        var xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(new Uri (weburl));
        doc.LoadXml (xml);
        foreach(XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("*"))
        {
             Console.Out.WriteLine(node.Name);
        }
```

Что делать, как быть?

Comment: А от нас вы что хотите? Идите к провайдеру своему и узнавайте, почему данный сайт у вас заблокирован, ищите VPN и используйте его, ищите альтернативу этому сайту в конце концов. Мы вам как помочь то должны?

Comment: Да и API_KEY свой светить здесь, наверное, не надо?

Comment: Ну я если честно не в курсе, как можно подключить VPN в приложении. В браузере я использую расширение для этого. А на счет ключа  - как то пофиг, он же фришный

Comment: Вы можете запускать ваше приложение при включенном VPN на сервере (в данном случае, думаю, это ваш компьютер), например Windscribe, или же смотреть в сторону прокси, которые нужно устанавливать перед отправкой запроса.

Comment: Блин, весь интернет облазил в поисках халявного VPN, так и не нашел. Спасибо большое